# Check if the previous value is changed and if changed put the previous value before changed in a log table and print that log table on screen

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to work on a worksheet in which user can change the value, but i want that when user change the value the previous value should store somewhere and then can be printed on a change log table on screen

I have tried the following code

```
$("classPreviousValue").on('focusin', function() {
    $(this).data('val', $(this).val());

});

$("classPreviousValue").on('change', function() {
  var $prev = $(this).data('val');
  var $current = $(this).val();
  if ($prev !== $current) {
      alert ("Things changed");
    $(this).css("color", $currentDayColor);
    $("#divChangeLog").html($("#divChangeLog").html() + "<br>Value changed from $prev");
 };


    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Classes start with a period `.classPreviousValue` not `classPreviousValue`. And try switching `on('focusin'` to `each` to loop through all of them without the need for user interaction. Also at the end of the `if` statement, change data-val to the new value.

```
$(".classPreviousValue").each(function() {
    $(this).data('val', $(this).val());
});

$(".classPreviousValue").on('change', function() {
  var $prev = $(this).data('val');
  var $current = $(this).val();
  if ($prev !== $current) {
      alert ("Things changed");
    $(this).css("color", $currentDayColor);
    $("#divChangeLog").html($("#divChangeLog").html() + "<br>Value changed from " + $prev);
    $(this).data('val',$current); //set data-val to new value
   };
 });
```

Comment: What if i want to see the changes i made in the Select input or drop down menu

Comment: @Z7272727 I would try asking a new question with the updated code. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask